# Converting string like "2019-03-15T21:30:00Z" into just a year in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new to Python and I have a relatively simple problem but I just can't find a solution on the internet.
I read in strings like "2019-03-15T21:30:00Z" into my program and I need to extract just the month and year from it, i.e March and 2019.
Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import datetime
a = "2019-03-15T21:30:00Z"
datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').year
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just what I needed.